# Showing that an integral can not be expressed in terms of elementary functions

Tags: integration, intuition, indefinite-integrals

I recently encountered an integral of the form:
$$\int{\frac{\log(a+bx+\sqrt{x^2+c})}{x}}dx$$
The result involves the dilogarithm function, but I was wondering if there is a fast way of showing that the integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. I am aware of the existence of the Risch Algorithm, but I thought there may be a more intuitive way.

Is there such a method?

Comment: $\int\frac{\log(a+bx)}{x}\mathrm dx$ is easily transformed so that it looks like the definition of the dilogarithm, but I'm not sure that what you have is as amenable to such recognition...

Comment: @J.M. - I realize that, but say I never heard of the dilogarithm, how would I know that this integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions? 
"You can't" would also be a valid answer I guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can refer you to this paper : http://www.claymath.org/programs/outreach/academy/LectureNotes05/Conrad.pdf.

Comment: It will take me a while to figure this out specifically for the dilogarithm, but I see the general direction. Thanks!

Comment: Link gone. Try http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/elemint.pdf